# jQuery event handler only works for first element

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I can't seem to figure out why only the first element invokes my event handler that displays an alert.  I found other similar questions on Stack Overflow that related to using IDs rather than classes, but that's not my issue.

When I click on the 'x' next to the first element it displays the alert as expected, but fails to do so for the other elements that were added dynamically with the append button.

Here's a minimal, but complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $(function() {

     $(".append").click(function(){

      $('.container').append('<div class="box"></div>')
      $('.box:last').append('<div class="text"><span>ABCDEFG</span><br/></div>')
      $('.box:last').append('<a href="#" class="test">x</a>')

     });

      $("a.test").click(function() {
      alert("works only for the first item in the list");


     });


   });


});

</script>
   <style>
      .box {
          padding:3px;
          margin-bottom:3px;
          border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
          width:550px;
      }
      .box:hover{background-color:#fff;}

      #container {
          position:relative;
      }

      .text {
          float:left;
          width:300px;
          font-size:13px;
      }
      .text span {
          font-size:18px;
          line-height:23px;
          font-weight:700;
      }

   </style>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="container">

     <input type="button" class="append" value="Append">

      <div class="box">
     <div class="text"><span>ABCDEFG</span></div>
     <a href="#" class="test">x</a>
     </div>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$("a.test").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("a.test").live('click', function() {
```

The reason why only the first element is working is because at the time the `click` event is attached, there is only one `<a>` element on the page. You need to explicitly add the click event handler to every anchor that is created, or use live events instead. Read more about [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handlers.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I'm learning jQuery and was stumped by this problem for a few days.  Thanks for a clear, concise answer.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and its usage is discouraged even on project using older versions of jQuery.

Comment: @saluce - good point, but when I wrote this answer, `live` was vey much alive and flourishing.

Answer (score 2):

When you hook up event handlers with [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (`click` is a shortcut for `bind("click", ...)`), only elements that already exist are hooked up. New ones you add later are not.

You can use the <s>[`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or</s> [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function, or the delegation features of the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function, or hook them up individually when you add them:

- [Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyivu6/3) - Using the latest jQuery and `delegate` (you can also use `on`, but I like how `delegate` documents my intent):

  ```
  jQuery(function($) {

    $("#theButton").click(function() {
      $("#container").append(
        "<div><a class='test' href='#'>X</a></div>"
      );
    });

    $("#container").delegate("a.test", "click", function() {
      alert("Clicked");
    });

  });
  ```
- [Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyivu6/4) - Using the latest jQuery and `on` (note that the order of arguments is different from `delegate`):

  ```
  jQuery(function($) {

    $("#theButton").click(function() {
      $("#container").append(
        "<div><a class='test' href='#'>X</a></div>"
      );
    });

    $("#container").on("click", "a.test", function() {
      alert("Clicked");
    });

  });
  ```
- [Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyivu6/2) - Using your jQuery vesion *(1.3.0?!)* and hooking them up as you add them:

  ```
  jQuery(function($) {

    $("#theButton").click(function() {
      $("<div><a class='test' href='#'>X</a></div>")
        .click(aTestClick)
        .appendTo("#container");
    });

    $("a.test").click(aTestClick);

    function aTestClick() {
      alert("Clicked");
    }

  });
  ```

---

Off-topic (slightly):

1. jQuery 1.3.0 is ***nine*** releases and more than two years out of date. Current release *(as of the original answer, March 2011)* is 1.5.1, and even if you want to stick with the 1.3 tree, there were not one but two maintenance releases after 1.3.0.
2. You're using two separate `ready` calls, first the explicit one, then an implicit one (your `$` where you pass in a function). Only one is necessary.
3. Strongly recommend *not* relying on semicolon insertion, it's the spawn of the devil. End your statements with semicolons, to ensure scripts can be minified/compressed/packed and just because the interpreter can guess wrong sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  I'm actually using the latest version of jQuery in my code, but I found something online that was apparently a little old that used the then current version and that's what I based my minimal example on.  Thanks for mentioning the two ready calls as well --- I'm just getting up to speed on jQuery and appreciate the pointer.  I'm coming from Python where semantically significant whitespace is the norm --- need to get in the habit of ending statements with semicolons.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Raj: No worries, hope that helped! Best,

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated is 1.7, and it is recommended to use `.on()` for 1.7 and up, or `.delegate()` before 1.7.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was a mistake, I didn't notice timestamps until it was too late to reverse the vote =/

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler isn't being added to subsequently appended elements.  There are several ways to attach the event handler dynamically.  For newer versions of jQuery (1.7+), use the `.on()` function with a selector.

```
$('.container').on('click', 'a.live', function() { alert("I'm on"); });
```

Older versions of jQuery don't have `.on()`, so you can use `.live()`.  However, one caveat is that `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7.

```
$('a.live').live('click', function() { alert("I'm live"); });
```

Even the jQuery team suggests using alternatives to `.live()`, regardless of the version of jQuery you are using.  For versions older than 1.7, use `.delegate()`.

```
$('.container').delegate('a.test', 'click', function() { alert("I'm delegated"); });
```